# Web part title not showing after exported?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, web-part, export

I export the about me web part from my sites and I added it to another page, title is not showing,I changed the Chrome type to title only by editing the web part properties, but it again reset to none.

I referred this links but it's not working

http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.in/2012/12/webpart-chrome-type-is-not-working-or.html#.V-qFcPl97Dd

Answer (score 0):

Try export web part as shown in this link [Export any web part from a SharePoint page](https://chuvash.eu/2014/09/19/export-any-web-part-from-a-sharepoint-page/).. And then import that in you page...